# Synchronous equivalent way of $.getJSON

Tags: jquery

I have this code sample which returns data in JSON format to put into slickGrid:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function() { dataReturn.push(this); });
    ...
    myDataView.setItems(dataReturn); 
    ...
});
```

but I am looking for a synchronous way and I tried something like this:

```
var dataReturn = JSON.stringfy( $.ajax({url:"...", async: false }).responseText );
myDataView.setItems(dataReturn);
```

but seems it isn't really the same...what I have missed?

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Luigi

Comment: Due respect, you're solving the wrong problem. Rather than trying to make ajax synchronous, which makes for a poor UX, doesn't work in all cases (for instance, if your URL is triggering JSONP rather than XHR), and is unnecessary. Instead, embrace the event-driven, asynchronous nature of modern web programming. If you're having a specific problem doing that, post a question about *that*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` and set `async : false` like this

```
$.ajax({
        url:url, 
        dataType : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(data) { 
            $.each(data, function() { dataReturn.push(this); });
             ...
            myDataView.setItems(dataReturn); 
            ...
            }
});
```

Comment: That'll work (for now) provided the `$.getJSON` call isn't relying on JSONP rather than XHR (`$.getJSON` does both, depending on whether there's a `callback=?` or similar in the URL).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `dataType` argument (see [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)):

`$.getJSON()` is a shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

Try to **avoid synchronous calls** though. Quote from [jQuery doc (see async prop)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support
>   synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily
>   lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

You might want to try jQuery [Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url);
jqxhr.done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() { dataReturn.push(this); });
        ...
        myDataView.setItems(dataReturn); 
        ...
    });
});
```